# Appending multiple Google dorks in a single query

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners, google-dorks

My goal is to look up multiple vulns in a single google search for a particular site. (Because google makes me pay for more than 100 search api calls per day).

Let's say I have 3 dorks:  `index of /htdocs` and `"Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error." ext:xml` and `"[function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"` 
I would like to see if either of those messages has been indexed in Google for example.com.

Using OR in between those dorks doesn't seem to give me the required results.(I tried variants of `dork1 OR dork2 or dork3 AND site:example.com`)

Comment: this is not a security question, but a Google-specific syntax question - and you appear to be trying to get around a limitation that they want you to pay for ...

Comment: Do you suggest moving it to a different stackexchange site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using brackets around the dorks separated with '|' and using AND operator for the sitename would do the trick.

For example, the solution to the example problem in question would be:

```
("index of /htdocs" | "Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error." | "[function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in") AND site:example.com
```

This would search for those three dorks in example.com.

[Answer credit](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsecstudents/comments/6soslg/ways_for_appending_multiple_google_dorks_in_a/)

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is not infosec based, but anyway. In your queries, you can use 'AND' and 'OR' operands via their symbols '&' and '|'. There are further information about operands and other information about Google dork [here](http://www.google-dorking.com/). Also, you can see example queries with Google Hacking Database (GHDB) in expoit-db [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/google-hacking-database/?ghdb_search_text).